# {"errors":{"errors":[{"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action.","code":"permission_denied"}]}}

Tags: django, api, django-cors-headers

When I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` after running `python manage.py runserver` inside my virtual env I got this error permission denied
my Django is still in the default folder structure and no change yet
I have tried to instll `pip install django-cors-headers` and add all the below into the  `setting.py file` file

```
from corsheaders.middleware import CorsMiddleware
from corsheaders.middleware import CorsMiddleware
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALL_ALL =True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.example\.com$",
]
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r"^/api/.*$"
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware"
]
```

Comment: Can you show the urls.py and the view that handles the `/` path?

Comment: You set the wrong port in your `CORS_ALLOWD_ORIGINS`. The last line should be `"http://127.0.0.1:8000",` and not `9000`

Comment: I did this too, but didn't work, I just deleted it and  run `django-admin startproject mysite`

Answer (score 0):

it was just the Django App initial boilerplate project( the basic structure)
so I have deleted it and run again `django-admin startproject mysite`